# Is std::max_element a C++11 x feature?

Tags: c++, c++11

Do you know if std::max_element is C++11 feature or it has existed before
that. 
I am using g++ 4.8.3 and does not throw warning messages requesting to use -std=c++11

I am posting the code so that it may help people to compile on their machines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        explicit A(int x): x(x) {}
        bool operator<(const A& a) { return x < a.x; }
};

int
main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    v.push_back(A(20));
    v.push_back(A(10));
    v.push_back(A(15));
    v.push_back(A(5));

    A result(*(std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end())));
    std::cout << result.x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What prevented you from simply looking it up? Or trying it in C++03?

Comment: Apologies. 
It does compile with C++03.

Answer (score 3):

`std::max_element` has existed since the very first C++ standard.